# Does lack of a zero element imply two groups are not isomorphic?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

Let $F$ be a field. I am trying to show $F^\times$ contains no subgroup which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$. For obvious reasons, I am only considering the finite subgroups of $F^\times$. I know one way to do it is to recognize that a subgroup of the multiplicative group is cyclic and $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$ is not, so they cannot be isomorphic. However, to test my understanding I'm trying to justify it a different way.

Are we allowed to say that they aren't isomorphic because $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$ has a zero element and $F^\times$ does not, so no subgroup of $F^\times$ could contain a zero element? Or does that not work because even if a subgroup of $F^\times$ doesn't have a zero element, it can still have an element which is mapped to the zero element of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$?

Comment: I think you're confused. $F^\times$ has a *unit* element, namely $1_F$, because $1_F \cdot x = x = x \cdot 1_F$ for all $x$. Similarly $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$ has a *unit* element, $(0,0)$, because $(0,0) + (x,y) = (x,y) = (x,y) + (0,0)$.

Comment: There is a general result that a finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of any field is cyclic.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Okay, that's kind of what I thought which is why I was skeptical. So F×=F∖{0}F×=F∖{0} doesn't have the element {0}{0}, but it does have a unit element which means there is an element that can get mapped to the unit element of Z2×Z4Z2×Z4, right? So I can't reason that a lack of the zero element would imply the groups are not isomorphic?

Comment: @DerekHolt I'm aware of that fact, I'm just wondering if my justification based on lack of a zero element works to check my understanding of the material.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The groups $U(2) = \{1,-1\}$ (2nd roots of unity under multiplication) and $\mathbb{Z}_2 = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} = \{0,1\}$ (Integers modulo 2 under addition) are isomorpic via the isomorphism $1 \mapsto 0$ and $-1 \mapsto 1$.

Hence you cannot argue as you do. The identity element must be mapped to the identity element, that is correct, but an identity element can be written as 0 in additive notation, but could be written as $1$ in multiplicative notation. In $U(2)$ the identity element is $1$, and in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ the identity element is $0$. A commutative group written muliplicatively may be isomorphic to a group written additively.

Comment: I think better is to say "Identity mapped to identity" than "Unity mapped to unity.

Comment: That's what I thought and this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: the group $\mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/4$ has $4$ elements satisfying $x^2 = e$ ( in mulplicative notation). However, in a field the equation $x^2 = 1$ has at most $2$ solutions.